# How can data be retrieved from this port?

Tags: security, keyboard, computer-architecture, keylogger

I saw an image on a social network saying that if your using a public computer do not use the one which has the following port on it as your data can be extracted out.
Now I am wondering how can your personal data be extracted? Is this port for system sharing? Please help out. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Why is this concept causing you to wander? I am just wondering.

Comment: Not all know English well.

Comment: You knew it, you just mistyped it.

Answer (score 2):

What you have posted a picture of is a **physical keyboard sniffer / keylogger** ([similar to this device](http://www.keelog.com/diy.html)).  That small unit will intercept all key presses from the attached [PS/2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector) keyboard, and store it in the device.  At a later date, the person who placed the keylogger can then retrieve the unit, and know exactly what keys were pressed on the keyboard by everyone who used the computer.

Your personal data can be "extracted" because when the attacker is viewing the keylog, any usernames and passwords that you typed will show up in the keystream.  All the attacker has to do is look for key-words (Facebook, Hotmail, etc...), and then determine your username/password combo from the resulting keys.

Comment: @StartupCrazy To answer your specific question, data is retrieved by opening up notepad and pressing a specific series of keys. This will cause the device to replay everything in it's memory into the text document.